Law & Order: Special Victims Unit episode with a rooftop raid
I feel a little embarrassed by this, as I usually know my Law & Order: Special Victims Unit well, but I've been searching and can't seem to find which particular episode this scene constitutes.
There's a scene early on in an episode where the detectives hear a scream while inside a building, burst onto a roof in broad daylight, where they interrupt what they initially think is a rape, as a man is forcing himself onto a woman. However, when they intervene, a man with a camera asks them what they're doing and it is revealed that it's an independent rape porn production. Afterwards, the detectives question the filmmakers and express their disgust at them turning rape into entertainment.
I initially thought that it was a part of the episode "Smut", as I thought that the scene of Benson and Tutuola have an argument about porn happened in the same episode. However, I'm having my doubts about this and have been led to believe that they're from separate episodes.
Does this sound familiar? Can any SVU fans confirm what episode this interrupted rape porn scene was from?
EDIT #1: I've added some pertinent details, such as the scream heard from down below and that it took place in broad daylight, to enhance the search. I'm pretty sure it wasn't Smut or Rooftops.
EDIT #2: It may have taken place inside an apartment... just the gist is that the detectives bust a shoestring budget independent rape entertainment crew.

Smut seems to be the only episode where that type of video is a topic. there are several episodes where they crash a porn set. I think you may be mixing scenes.

@cde That's certainly a possibility. I'm just wondering where I saw the scene of them bursting onto an open rape simulation set was.

maybe the episode where a group staged a kidnapping and rape in order to force the cops to do their job in locating a kidnapped little brother? s12e16, Spectacle.

Hmm, no... Damn, I really wonder where this scene where they interrupt a fake rape on a rooftop takes place. I'll amend my description, as I know it takes place early in the episode.

I think you mean Manipulated (season 7, episode 15). It begins with cops bursting into the wrong room after reports of screaming, mistakenly stumbling into an amateur film. From an online summary:

The scene opens on a blonde woman screaming.  She is tied to a bed and a menacing figure in a ski mask is advancing upon her when the door to the apartment bursts open, admitting two police officers, guns drawn.  They order the man in the ski mask to stop what he's doing.  The camera pans to the right to find...another camera.  A young man who can only be described as the result of an unholy union between Elvis Costello and Gollum expresses glee at the arrival of the cops and orders the cameraman to get a close-up of "the fat one".  Shortly, the cops discover that no one has called 911 on these kids making a "student film" (is that what they're calling amateur porn now?).  They quickly ascertain that they were given the wrong apartment number and they haul ass to the correct apartment, where they discover the body of another blonde.  This one, however, is well and truly dead.

EDIT: As the OP mentioned, this is actually most likely a scene from Lunacy (Season 10, episode 4). It begins with a body floating in a river, and the team notices some people on a nearby roof. They rush to it when they hear screaming and find a man attacking a woman but realize it's actually an adult film. But the footage they shot later helps the investigation.

Someone on IMDb just pinpointed the scene as being a part of "Lunacy", where it takes place immediately after a mutilated woman's body is discovered. I can see why finding the episode was so difficult, as the series just becomes a giant blur after a while, with several similar scenes of bursting in on filmmaking take place.

@DarthBotto I think you're right. I just saw the opening scene and it does take place on a roof (or at least looks like it). Should I delete my answer?

No, I appreciate your answer and am happy to reward points. I think you answer actually shows how over-saturated the show has become, where we could have a dozen episodes with similar descriptions as what I saw. I appreciate your help, really. ;)

@DarthBotto OK, I'll at least update it with the new info.
